# how to auto select an input field and the text in it on page load

Tags: javascript, html

Upon page load I want to move the cursor to a particular field.  No problem.  But I also need to select and highlight the default value that is placed in that text field.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

From http://www.codeave.com/javascript/code.asp?u_log=7004:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('myTextInput');
input.focus();
input.select();
```

```html
<input id="myTextInput" value="Hello world!" />
```

Comment: This works in Firefox but this will not select the text in Chrome or Edge.

Answer (score 42):

In your input tag, place the following:

```
onFocus="this.select()"
```

Comment: This only works in FireFox.  In Chrome you can kind of fix this by adding "onmouseup='return false'" but that won't solve the problem in Edge, nor does it solve the problem if you are using the keyboard to navigate into the element.

Comment: Just tried it and works on Chrome as well (`Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)`)

Comment: this works perfectly since my input were too many and I uses Class not ID

Answer (score 39):

try this. this will work on both Firefox and chrome.

> `<input type="text" value="test" autofocus onfocus="this.select()">`

Comment: Will this work with other input types like checkbox or radio?

Answer (score 17):

To do it on page load:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var input = document.getElementById('myTextInput');
  input.focus();
  input.select();
}
```

```html
<input id="myTextInput" value="Hello world!" />
```

Answer (score 5):

I found a very simple method that works well:

```
<input type="text" onclick="this.focus();this.select()">
```

Answer (score 5):

In your input tag use autofocus like this

```
<input type="text" autofocus>
```

Answer (score 2):

when using jquery...

html:

```
<input type='text' value='hello world' id='hello-world-input'>
```

jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $('#hello-world-input').focus().select();
});
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/seanmcmills/xmh4e0d4/

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can forgo `focus()` and just call `select()`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var input = document.getElementById('myTextInput');
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange( 6,  19 );
```

```html
    <input id="myTextInput" value="Hello default value world!" />
```

select particular text on textfield

Also you can use like

```
input.selectionStart = 6;
input.selectionEnd = 19;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `autofocus` attribute works well with text input and checkboxes.

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="boo" autofocus="autofocus"> FooBoo
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="boo" autofocus="autofocus"> FooBoo
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the input text field automatically get focus when the page loads:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" autofocus>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Source : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp