# select all text in input form in internet explorer 6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

i'm trying to get an input box to get auto-selected when the user clicks on it
the code i'm using :

```
<input type="text" onclick="this.focus();this.select();" value="i like pie">
```

tried with the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210761/how-to-auto-select-an-input-field-and-the-text-in-it-on-page-load)

the problem is that the code works for FF, Opera, Internet Explorer 8/7 but not for IE 6... any ideas how to make it work for IE6 too ?

Comment: FYI, the code you posted works in IE6 for me.

Comment: oddly enough, works on a different ie6 , but still fails in mine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works for me too.

If you don't have JavaScript enabled in your browser, your code wouldn't work. Check if JavaScript is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem in IE7, and tried wrapping it in a timeout, which worked...even a timeout of 0ms worked.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    target.select();
}, 0);
```