# TextBox missing definition of SelectAll(). Why is it missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to select all the text inside an asp:TextBox but it keeps saying:

**'TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'SelectAll' and no extension method accepting a first argument of type 'TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

I read that I need Systems.Windows.Forms so I added a reference to it but that didn't work. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and I've tried searching for answers and nothing.

This is the Default.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the Default.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in ASP/C# as it runs on the server-side. Text-selection is a client action. Try javascript's `.select()` method. Ex:

```
var input = document.getElementById('TextBox1');

input.focus();
input.select();
```

Source: [how to auto select an input field and the text in it on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210761/how-to-auto-select-an-input-field-and-the-text-in-it-on-page-load)